# SSL Error with Python Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

i wrote a simple code, basically the same as the one on https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-python and every time after the first attempt i've the same error :

```
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "C:/plug-ins/googleDrive.py", line 35, in <lambda>
#     self.authAction = self.menu.addAction( 'Authentication', lambda: self.runAuthentication()  )
#   File "C:/plug-ins/googleDrive.py", line 46, in runAuthentication
#     credentials = self.flow.step2_exchange( unicode(text) )
#   File "D:/Python\oauth2client\util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
#     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
#   File "D:/Python\oauth2client\client.py", line 1131, in step2_exchange
#     headers=headers)
#   File "D:/Python\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1597, in request
#     (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
#   File "D:/Python\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1345, in _request
#     (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
#   File "D:/Python\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1281, in _conn_request
#     conn.connect()
#   File "D:/Python\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1013, in connect
#     self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
#   File "D:/Python\httplib2\__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
#     cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
#   File "C:\python26\ssl.py", line 350, in wrap_socket
#   File "C:\python26\ssl.py", line 118, in __init__
#   File "C:\python26\ssl.py", line 293, in do_handshake
# ssl.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:480: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

I run this under Python 2.6.4, httplib2 v0.7.7 and google-api-python-client v1.0b9. If someone have an idea...I will be very grateful.

Comment: Said code would be useful to include, even if it's identical.

Answer (score 1):

That version of the google-api-python-client (v1.0b9) is beta 9 of the client library, you should upgrade to the release version, which is simply v1.0.

As for the "EOF occurred in violation of protocol", I have only seen that occur on a flaky network connection, is that the case here?